# Question concerning the spectrum of an element of $\mathscr{l}^1(\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: functional-analysis

I have the following question:

> $A=\mathscr{l}^1(\mathbb{Z})$ is a Banach Algebra using convolution as multiplication. I now would like to know, if there is a nice way to express the spectrum $\sigma(x)$ of an element $x\in A$.

I know, that $A=\mathscr{l}^1(\mathbb{Z})$ is isomorphic to the Wiener algebra and that $x\in A$ is invertible, iff $\mathscr{F}_x(\theta)\neq 0$ for all $\theta\in [0,1]$.

But I was still unable to find a nice expression...

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you look at the functions (whether on the unit circle or the unit interval, whichever normalisation you prefer), you have a simple criterion for invertibility. So what's the spectrum $\sigma(f)$ of a function in the Wiener algebra?